# Crud mongodb devuelve null

Tags: java, mongodb, crud

Estoy realizando un crud con SpringBoot y mongoDb en mi local, he añadido desde la consola de mongo un registro ->

```
db.articulo.save({"_id":ObjectId("90e"),"idPromocion":1,"numArticulos":"3","articulos":[{"nombre":"silla","color":"rojo","precio":"10€"},{"nombre":"mesa","color":"azul","precio":"2€"}],"entrega":"sabado"}
```

---

Y ahora para realizar el crud he creado el modelo

```
@Document
public class Articulo {

    private Integer idPromocion; 
    private Articulos art; 

    public Articulo(){}

    public Articulo(Integer idPromocion,Articulos art){
        this.idPromocion=idPromocion;
        this.art=art;
    }
    getters.setter...
 }


 public class Articulos {
  private String nombre; 
  private String color; 
  private String precio; 

  constructor, getter, setters
 }
 ---------------
```

El repositorio

```
    @Repository
    public interface ArticuloRepository extends CrudRepository<Articulo, String> 
 { }
```

Implementación

```
@Autowired
private ArticuloRepository repositorio;

     List<Articulo> list= (List<Articulo>) repositorio.findAll();
```

Después en la ejecución he comprobado los datos del list y me encuentro con los datos a null, al parecer no los recupera correctamente. Tengo otra colección con una estructura más simple y sí me los recupera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB al ser un tipo de base de datos no relacional, tiene sus propias características y, por tanto, su propio repositorio. En tu caso debes sustituir `CrudRepository` por `MongoRepository` que tiene su propio findAll que debería funcionarte.